# Having difficulty to concatenate condition and $_POST variables inside a variable

Tags: php

I would like to add this line of code

```
<?php echo(isset($_POST['AgentID'])&&($_POST['AgentID']=='')?' selected="selected"':'');?>
```

inside

```
$agentData.='<option value="'.$row['AgentID'].'">'.$row['AgentID'].' - '.$row['AgentName'].'</option>';
```

I'm having difficulty because of " " and ' ' due to $_POST variables has ' ' also

The whole code is:

```
<select name="AgentID" id="agentIDSentakushi">
      <option value="" <?php echo(isset($_POST['AgentID'])&&($_POST['AgentID']=='')?' selected="selected"':'');?>>--</option>
      <?php
                   $setsu = dbSetsuzoku();
                   $sql = 'SELECT AgentID,AgentName FROM agentdb ORDER BY AgentID';
                   $agentData='';
                   $result = $setsu->query($sql);
                    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                     {
                        $agentData.='<option value="'.$row['AgentID'].'">'.$row['AgentID'].' - '.$row['AgentName'].'</option>';
                     }
                    echo $agentData;
                    $setsu = null;
                  ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I don't get how you want to concatenate a condition on to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify it, do:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $selected = (isset($_POST['AgentID']) && $_POST['AgentID']==$row['AgentID'])?'selected="selected"':'';
  $agentData.='<option value="'.$row['AgentID'].'"'.$selected.'>'.$row['AgentID'].' - '.$row['AgentName'].'</option>';
}
```

`$selected` here is a variable which checks if `$_POST['AgentID']` is *set* and if it's *equal* to `$_POST['AgentID']`, if the conditions are true, that option will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about is using `vsprintf` like this:

```
$setsu = dbSetsuzoku();
$sql = "
    SELECT
        AgentID,
        AgentID AS AgentID_2, -- notice how I duplicated it here
        AgentName
    FROM agentdb
    ORDER BY AgentID
";
$agentData = '';
$result = $setsu->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $selected = (isset($_POST['AgentID']) && $_POST['AgentID'] == $row['AgentID']) ? ' selected' : '';
    $agentData .= vsprintf("<option value='%d'$selected>%d - %s</option>", $row);
}
echo $agentData;
$setsu = null;
```

The trick here is to select the parameters you will then later print in the same order (and quantity) in the SQL query since you will pass the returned array directly to `vsprintf` and the array returned from the SQL query needs to be in the same order as your `vsprintf` placeholders. Saves you a lot of confusing text :)